# Return JSON from custom VolleyCallback interface to calling method

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have the method below: What it does is that the method  userSignIn is called from another activity and returns a JsonObject,since my volley implementation does its calls asynchronously  I have implemented callback interface that fetches the result fron the **OnResponce** method. However the difficulty am facing is returning the JSONObject to the calling Activity.

```
@Override
public JSONObject userSignIn(String user, String pass,String version, String authType, String URL) throws Exception {

    urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(URL);
    urlBuilder.append("?uname=" + user);
    urlBuilder.append("&passwd=" + pass);
    urlBuilder.append("&ver=" + version);

    URI=urlBuilder.toString();


     VolleyLoginExecute(new VolleyCallback() {
         @Override
         public JSONObject onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
             responce = result;
             return responce;

         }


     });


    return responce;
}
public interface VolleyCallback{
    JSONObject onSuccess(JSONObject result);

}

public JSONObject VolleyLoginExecute(final VolleyCallback callback) {

    JsonObjectRequest LoginReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,URI, null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            if (response != null) {
                callback.onSuccess(response);

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        public Priority getPriority() {
            return priority;
        }
    };
    LoginReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    Acme_Application.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(LoginReq, tag_login_req);

    return responce;
}
```

I have tried this as well to return the JsonObject but it does not work as well

```
@Override
public JSONObject userSignIn(String user, String pass,String version, String authType, String URL) throws Exception {

    urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(URL);
    urlBuilder.append("?uname=" + user);
    urlBuilder.append("&passwd=" + pass);
    urlBuilder.append("&ver=" + version);

    URI=urlBuilder.toString();

    return VolleyLoginExecute(new VolleyCallback() {
        @Override
        public JSONObject onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
            responce = result;
            return responce;

        }


    });
}
```

How can I return the JsonObject to the calling activity successfully

Comment: You may pass the same VolleyCallback interface from calling activity or use another callback to get response from rest service class.

Comment: Correct me if am wrong,what you are suggesting is I implement another callback in the calling class that will get the data

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, or you can pass the same VolleyCallback to the method userSignIn() from calling class.

Comment: Would you mind helping me with an excrept of how the return code would look like what am trying is throwing tons of errors

Comment: This is what am doing // The callback interface
interface MyCallback {
    void callbackCall();
}

// The class that takes the callback
class Worker {
   MyCallback callback;

   void onEvent() {
      callback.callbackCall();
   }
}

// Option 1:

class Callback implements MyCallback {
   void callbackCall() {
      // callback code goes here
   }
}

worker.callback = new Callback();

Comment: i will post u the answer..please wait

Comment: if you need `activityB`(SignIn) to pass response to caller activity `ActivitA` use `startActivityForResult()` from A and set the result in an `intent` @ activityB

Comment: @Yazan that cannot work for me its not an activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void userSignIn(final VolleyCallback volleyCallback,String user, String pass,String version, String authType, String URL) throws Exception {

    urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(URL);
    urlBuilder.append("?uname=" + user);
    urlBuilder.append("&passwd=" + pass);
    urlBuilder.append("&ver=" + version);

    URI=urlBuilder.toString();

     VolleyLoginExecute(new VolleyCallback() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
           volleyCallback.onSuccess(result);
         }
     });
}  public interface VolleyCallback{
    void onSuccess(JSONObject result);
}      public void VolleyLoginExecute(final VolleyCallback callback) {
    JsonObjectRequest LoginReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,URI, null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            if (response != null) {
                callback.onSuccess(response);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        public Priority getPriority() {
            return priority;
        }
    };
    LoginReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    Acme_Application.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(LoginReq, tag_login_req);
}
```

Comment: Also you can pass the volleyCallback directly to VolleyLoginExecute() method

Comment: in the onSucess method VolleyCallback.onSuccess(result); cannot be refrenced from a static context as you have shown

Comment: use volleyCallback.onSuccess(result); instead of VolleyCallback.onSuccess(result);

Comment: Had to alter a few things but its fixed. Now thats setup, how do I call it from my activity or any other method

Comment: instance.userSignIn(new VolleyCallback() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {

         }
     });
  ,"user","pass","version","authType","url"
  }

Comment: Excellent works as expected..let me accept your answer